# How to know if the user has configured a mail app?

Tags: cocoa, email, nsworkspace

I'd like to disable an icon in my app if the user has not configured an application for email use -- as in, they could be using webmail with a browser. How can I know this?

Does `NSWorkspace openURL:` just fail silently when handed an `NSURL` created with `@"mailTo:..."` string if no app is ready to handle it?